# Memory Leak in NameCtrl Add On (for Presence) with IE and SharePoint 2010

Tags: 2010, bug, presence-indication

Is there known bug/memory leak in the NameCtrl browser addon (which is used for displaying presence information)?

I ask because I created a simple empty site based on the Blank site template and opened it in IE (9). I just refreshed the page continuously and watched task manager's available memmory shrink by about 10 MB on each refresh \ page load.

```
New-SPSite http://claims.spdev.com/sites/empty1 -OwnerAlias "spdev\dev" -Name "Empty 1" -Template "STS#1"
```

I loaded the same site in Google Chrome (17.0.963.83) and continually refreshed the page and no memory issues, which led me to believe something with IE.

I opened IE and went to the Add Ons management (Internet Options > Programs tab > Manage add-ons) to view the currently loaded add ons.  NameCtrl happened to be the first in my list, so I started there and disabled the Add On.  Closed my browser, reopened, refreshed my page, and no memory leak.  I re-enabled the add-on, started refreshing the page, and sure enough, the available memory began to shrink again on each refresh.

I left the NameCtrl on, and changed the "Person Name Actions and Presence Settings" option for my web application (Central Admin > Manage Web Applications > select web app > General Settings) from Yes to No.  I began refreshing my page and no more memory leak.

Some quick searches on the web seemed to indicate others experiencing the same.

Is this known?  Being worked on?

UPDATE:
I've tried in a separate environment with Vista + IE7 and cannot reproduce this issue, so it may be specific to the version of IE in use?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Seems to be fix in the July 2012 CU :
http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;2598373

Answer (score 1):

Yes, thats already known since at least 2011. It seems to be an IE9 specific issue.
There is also an answer from a Microsoft guy but without a real answer...

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/ieitprocurrentver/thread/3e561ee8-43bf-47dd-a7d4-a5db7b69379f